# Is it possible to optimize a query that gets all the rows in a table

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have this query

```
SELECT id, alias, parent FROM `content`
```

Is there a way to optimize this query so 'type' is different than 'all'

id - primary, unique

id - index

parent - index

alias - index

....

Note that this query will almost never return more than 1500 rows.

Thank you

Comment: As I understand question - NO. But optimization is possible in use this query: what is next life of queried data?

Comment: You could optimize it by deleting some rows :p

Comment: Jacek - not sure what you mean

Comment: Drew - for some reason it gets picked up by  the slow query report, but it doesn't make sense as every time I run it on phpmyadmin I get 0.00XXs. Could be that this is a new server that was used for developlment so data is skewed

Comment: well even MySQL workbench limits to 1000 rows. They figure one really didn't mean to bring back 31.2M rows

Comment: what is `select count(*) from content` ?

Comment: I corrected my answer above, I have tables from 500 to 1300 rows

Comment: `select @@version,@@long_query_time,@@slow_query_log,@@datadir,@@slow_query_log_file; `It would be troubling that 600 rows comes back slow. If it does it sounds like you have a highly compromised fractional (read: cheap?) setup in the cloud or some other problem

Comment: See [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/83oN6lQ.jpg) from this doc [Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time)

Comment: You have a book. You have to read the book. Can you read the book faster by using the book's index (the part where all chapters are enumerated by pages and short description)? If the answer to that question is yes, then you can optimize the query. Since it's not physically possible to do that in this universe, then the answer is no. Alternatively, you don't have to read the book which is the fastest possible feat.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fetching all the rows, so by definition it's going to report "ALL" as the query type in the EXPLAIN report. The only other possibility is the "index" query type, an index-scan that visits every entry in the index. But that's virtually the same cost as a table-scan.

There's a saying that the fastest SQL query is one that you don't run at all, because you get the data some other way.

For example, if the data is in a cache of some type. If your data has no more than 1500 rows, and it doesn't change frequently, it may be a good candidate for putting in memory. Then you run the SQL query only if the cached data is missing.

There are a couple of common options:

- The [MySQL query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) is an in-memory cache maintained in the MySQL server, and purged automatically when the data in the table changes.
- [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) is a popular in-memory key-value store used frequently by applications that also use MySQL. It's very fast. Another option is [Redis](http://redis.io/), which is similar but is also backed by disk storage.

Answer (score 0):

Turn `OFF` `log_queries_not_using_indexes`; it clutters the slow log with red herrings like what you got.

`0.00XX` seconds -- good enough not to worry.

`ALL` is actually optimal for fetching multiple columns from 'all' rows of a table.